# Titanium studio get current locations using background services?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

In my iOS app,I am getting current locations using setInterval I am able to get the current locations.

My issue is, even if my app when it is into background also need to get the current locations and save into DB?

will any one guide me how to do that?

My code in app.js

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('pause', function(e) {
        // register a background service. this JS will run when the app is backgrounded
    //checking that switch is ON/OFF
        if (Ti.App.Properties.getString('getLocation') == 'YES') {
        //timer = setInterval(Titanium.Geolocation.addEventListener('location', locationCallBack1), 10000);
        service = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({
            url : '/mainWindows/bg.js'
        });
        }

});
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this post over at the appcelerator forum: [Location tracking in the background with iOS](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/127523/location-tracking-in-the-background-with-ios)

It makes use of iOS background services, which are well explained in the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService):

```
// The app is transtioning to background here
Ti.App.addEventListener('pause', function(e){
    // Register background service
    bgService = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({ url: 'bgService.js' });
    Ti.API.info("registered background service = "+ bgService);
});
```

Comment: mwfire, thank you for response even I followed the same url given by you. In my app, I have one window to to enable/disable the locations,for this I used a switch ON/OFF. If I am in the same screen I getting the lat&long values and even by selecting this window, if I minimized my app it is working. when I jump to other window/screen or other tab. I am not getting the lat&long values, will you please help me come out from this issue. thanks in advance

Comment: You might have to update your tiapp.xml explicitly to enable Geolocation over a longer period without being switched off. You can find further details here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/tiapp.xml_and_timodule.xml_Reference-section-29004921_tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-UIBackgroundModes

`<string>location</string>`
Let me know if it works!

Comment: Moreover, setting `Ti.Geolocation.trackSignificantLocationChange = true;` might be a better approach to tracking geolocation in the background. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-property-trackSignificantLocationChange